# partition problem as installing windows 7 or 8 after ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows

I have Ubuntu already installed and I want to install Windows but it says 
"`we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one`"
here is my partition table tell me what is wrong

[image]

Any advice ?!

Comment: do you want to remove Ubuntu away ?

Comment: This isnt a GPT table....

Comment: @begueradj no I don't want that...no hope ?!

Comment: @Virusboy tell me then, please .

Comment: @begueradj I can remove ubuntu in sda1 but not home in sda5...can this fix it ??

Comment: You are trying to install Windows after installing Ubuntu: this means you will have only access to Windows. You must install Windows and only after that you can install Ubuntu. This is something too basic you can find in any beginner´s tutorials. Plus, with GParted, you can reformat/add/remove partitions as you want. Learn first  how to use GParted and the meaning of filesystems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved !
windows needed a primary partition and sda6 wasn't so by deleting it shrinking sda5 and extended partition, I got a new partition that was allowed to be primary and installed without removing anything.